# Training Accuracy & Validation Accuracy remain constant right from the first epoch

Tags: python, keras, 3d, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

This is my first time posting a question, please pardon me if it wasn't written or structured well.

---

The dataset consists of images in TIF format. Which means I am running a 3D CNN.

These images are simulated X-Ray images and the dataset has 2 classes; Normal and Anomaly. 
Their labels would be **'0'** for Normal and **'1'** for Anomaly.

The tree of my folders look like this:

1. Train

   - Normal
   - Anomaly
2. Validation

   - Normal
   - Anomaly

---

What I have done was initialise 2 arrays; 
**train** and **y_train**.

I ran a FOR loop which imports and appends the **Normal** images into **train**, and append a **'0'** into **y_train** for each image appended. So if I have 10 Normal images in train, I will have ten **'0'** s in **y_train** as well.

This is repeated for the **Anomaly** images and they are appended into **train** and a **'1'** will be appended into **y_train** as well. This means **train** consists of **Normal** images followed by **Anomaly** images. And **y_train** consists of **'0'** s, followed by **'1'** s.

Another FOR loop is executed for the validation folder, whereby my arrays are **test** and **y_test**.

---

This is my code for my Neural Network:

```
def vgg1():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name="block1_conv1", input_shape=(128, 128, 128, 1), data_format="channels_last")) # 64
    model.add(Conv3D(16, (3, 3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name="block1_conv2", data_format="channels_last")) # 64
    model.add(MaxPooling3D((2,2, 2), strides=(2,2, 2),padding='same', name='block1_pool'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 

    model.add(Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name="block2_conv1", data_format="channels_last")) # 128
    model.add(Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name="block2_conv2", data_format="channels_last")) # 128
    model.add(MaxPooling3D((2,2, 2), strides=(2,2, 2),padding='same', name='block2_pool'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
    model.add(Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name="block3_conv1", data_format="channels_last")) # 256
    model.add(Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name="block3_conv2", data_format="channels_last")) # 256
    model.add(Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name="block3_conv3", data_format="channels_last")) # 256
    model.add(MaxPooling3D((2,2, 2), strides=(2,2, 2),padding='same', name='block3_pool'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 

    model.add(Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name="block4_conv1", data_format="channels_last")) # 512
    model.add(Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name="block4_conv2", data_format="channels_last")) # 512
    model.add(Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name="block4_conv3", data_format="channels_last")) # 512
    model.add(MaxPooling3D((2,2, 2), strides=(2,2, 2),padding='same', name='block4_pool'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 

    model.add(Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name="block5_conv1", data_format="channels_last")) # 512 
    model.add(Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name="block5_conv2", data_format="channels_last")) # 512 
    model.add(Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name="block5_conv3", data_format="channels_last")) # 512 
    model.add(MaxPooling3D((2,2, 2), strides=(2,2, 2),padding='same', name='block5_pool'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 

    model.add(Flatten(name='flatten'))
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu',name='fc1')) 

    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu',name='fc2'))  

    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='predictions'))  
    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

---

The following code is the initialisation of **x_train**, **y_train**, **x_test**, **y_test** and model.compile.

I have also converted my labels into one-hot encoding.

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical


model = vgg1()

model.compile(
  loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
  optimizer='adam',
  metrics=['accuracy']
)

x_train = np.load('/content/drive/My Drive/3D Dataset v2/x_train.npy')
y_train = np.load('/content/drive/My Drive/3D Dataset v2/y_train.npy')
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
x_test = np.load('/content/drive/My Drive/3D Dataset v2/x_test.npy')
y_test = np.load('/content/drive/My Drive/3D Dataset v2/y_test.npy')
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
```

---

**This is the problem I want to highlight, which is the constant training accuracy and validation accuracy** .

```
Train on 127 samples, validate on 31 samples
Epoch 1/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1700s 13s/step - loss: 1.0030 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5842 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 2/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1708s 13s/step - loss: 0.5813 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5728 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 3/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1693s 13s/step - loss: 0.5758 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5720 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 4/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1675s 13s/step - loss: 0.5697 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5711 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 5/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1664s 13s/step - loss: 0.5691 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5785 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 6/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1666s 13s/step - loss: 0.5716 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5710 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 7/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1676s 13s/step - loss: 0.5702 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5718 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 8/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1664s 13s/step - loss: 0.5775 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5718 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 9/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1660s 13s/step - loss: 0.5753 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5711 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 10/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1681s 13s/step - loss: 0.5756 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5714 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 11/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1679s 13s/step - loss: 0.5675 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5710 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 12/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1681s 13s/step - loss: 0.5779 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5741 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 13/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1682s 13s/step - loss: 0.5763 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5723 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 14/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1685s 13s/step - loss: 0.5732 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5714 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 15/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1685s 13s/step - loss: 0.5701 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5710 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 16/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1678s 13s/step - loss: 0.5704 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5733 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 17/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1663s 13s/step - loss: 0.5692 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5710 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 18/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1657s 13s/step - loss: 0.5731 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5717 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 19/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1674s 13s/step - loss: 0.5708 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5712 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 20/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1666s 13s/step - loss: 0.5795 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5730 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 21/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1671s 13s/step - loss: 0.5635 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5753 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 22/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1672s 13s/step - loss: 0.5713 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5718 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 23/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1672s 13s/step - loss: 0.5666 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5711 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 24/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1669s 13s/step - loss: 0.5695 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5724 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
Epoch 25/25
127/127 [==============================] - 1663s 13s/step - loss: 0.5675 - accuracy: 0.7480 - val_loss: 0.5721 - val_accuracy: 0.7419
```

---

What is wrong and what can I do to rectify this? I presume that having a constant accuracy is undesirable.

Comment: Start with tinkering learning rate from 0.1 to 0.0001. Also your sample size is very low. You have to augment it somehow.

Comment: I've lowered the learning rate to 0.0001 but the accuracies remain the same. I will try it with data augmentation as well